# Redhat freezes when running Team Explorer Everywhere with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, redhat

I have a C++ project in Eclipse (Galileo), using TFS as my source control via Team Explorer Everywhere, on a Redhat (5.4) Enterprise server.

Sometimes (about 1 in 3) when I build my solution the server completely freezes up and nothing I can do will free it up short of performing a hard reset of the server.

The server was clean a few weeks ago and all that has been added to it is Redhat and Eclipse

Anyone else experienced this? Any ideas on how to cure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who's interested in this, I'm pretty sure that it was just me having very little RAM (I only had 1Gb, which maxes out before it crashes), currently going through the system to aquire some more...

Comment: Upgraded the server I'm using. It now has 8GBs of RAM and has yet to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Go to to terminal and type **top** command to see which process consumes the maximum resources of the system, so that you can analyze that your TFS server consumes maximum resource or some other application. In graphical mode you can monitor using system-monitor.

Comment: As I've said below; it's due to RAM usage, it maxes out and then the machine freezes.